# MySQLi prepared insert statement does not produce error and does not save to database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i have with php MySQLi prepared query, the query does not produce any errors though it does not do anything, here is the php code

```
    $db = SecureConnect(); //initialize connection
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `twitter_users`(`fullnames`, `email_address`, `password`, `twitter_id`, `twitter_username`, `screen_name`, `oauth_access_token`, `oauth_access_token_secret`, `PhoneNumber`, `dsate_created`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"); ; //mysql statement
if ( false===$db ) {
  die('prpe() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}

$stmt->bind_param($names, $email, $password, $_POST['user_id'],$username, $_POST['screen_name'],$_POST['oauth_token'] , $_POST['oauth_token_secret'],$number, $date );
if ( false===$stmt ) {
  die('bind() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}

$stmt->execute();
if ( false===$stmt ) {
  die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}

$db->commit();
$stmt->close();
$db->close();
```

The Secure connect function is correct since i use it with select query which works fine, what is the problem with my code?

Comment: Read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php `$stmt->bind_param('sssd', $code, $language, $official, $percent);` you're not doing that.

Comment: Thanks that will surely help

Comment: you're welcome. Remember to also use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php just in case.

Comment: I agree with @Fred-ii-. However; you should get an error. Check your error log. Check your error log level. Check the display error setting.

Comment: one question though, does it mean each of my 10 fields must be repressented in the 'ssd' area?

Comment: My favourite way to run *mysqli* is to have it throw exceptions. No need to check for `false` return values. Add this before creating the `mysqli` instance - `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: yep. each must have the same amount and the correct type

Comment: @MainaWycliffe yes. The first arg to `mysqli_stmt::bind_param` is the parameter type mask

Comment: that clears everything for me, thanks you all the help, i really appreciate it

Comment: you're very much welcome, *cheers* Maina.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed when reading your code that your if statements are wrong. Also the order of the IF statements should be reordered.

1. Connection validation should happen before trying to prepare the sql statement
2. In `$stmt` will be false in case prepare fails
3. The function `bind_param()` will return `false`, and not make the `$stmt` instance `false`.
4. Same as point 3 for: `execute()`
5. Add the param type mask 'sssdssssds' // Mentioned in the comments above

   ```
   $db = SecureConnect(); //initialize connection
   if ( false===$db ) {
       die('connect() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($db->error));
   }
   $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `twitter_users`(`fullnames`, `email_address`, `password`, `twitter_id`, `twitter_username`, `screen_name`, `oauth_access_token`, `oauth_access_token_secret`, `PhoneNumber`, `dsate_created`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"); ; //mysql statement
   if ( false===$stmt ) {
       die('prpe() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
   }

   $bind = $stmt->bind_param('sssdssssds', $names, $email, $password, $_POST['user_id'],$username, $_POST['screen_name'],$_POST['oauth_token'] , $_POST['oauth_token_secret'],$number, $date );
   if ( false===$bind ) {
      die('bind() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
   }
   if ( false===$stmt->execute() ) {
      die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
   }

   $db->commit();
   $stmt->close();
   $db->close();
   ```